On the Glaisher numbers and $6^5\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(6n+1)^5} = \frac{(2^5-1)(3^5-1)}2\,\zeta(5)+\frac{22}{\sqrt3}\,\pi^5$
I. Data
After some experimenting, we find for odd powers $s>1$,
\begin{align}
3^s\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(3n+1)^s} &= \frac{(3^s-1)}2\,\zeta(s)+\frac{G(s)}{2\, s!\sqrt3}\,(2\pi)^s\\[5pt]
4^s\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(4n+1)^s} &= \frac{2^s(2^s-1)}2\,\zeta(s)+\frac{E(s)}{4\, (s-1)!}\,(2\pi)^s\\[5pt]
6^s\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(6n+1)^s} &= \frac{(2^s-1)(3^s-1)}2\,\zeta(s)+\frac{H(s)}{2\, (s-1)!\sqrt3}\,(2\pi)^s
\end{align}
where,
\begin{align}
G(s) &= 1, 5, 49, 809,\dots\\[2pt]
E(s) &= 1, 5, 61, 1385,\dots\\[2pt]
H(s) &= 3, 33, 903, 46113,\dots\\
\tfrac13H(s)=H'(s) &= 1, 11, 301, 15371,\dots
\end{align}
and checking the OEIS reveals the three sequences to be the Glaisher G-numbers (A002111), Euler numbers (A000364), and Glaisher H-numbers (A002112), respectively. The related Glaisher H'-numbers (A002114) is also included.
In his paper, Glaisher pointed out connections to Eulerian numbers. And  based on our previous posts, we suspect there are level-$7$ relations as well,
$$14^3\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac1{(14n+1)^3}+\frac1{(14n+9)^3}+\frac1{(14n+11)^3}\right) = \frac{(2^3-1)(7^3-1)}2\,\zeta(3)+\color{blue}{8}\times\frac{2^2}{2!}\sqrt7\,\pi^3$$
$$14^5\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac1{(14n+1)^5}+\frac1{(14n+9)^5}+\frac1{(14n+11)^5}\right) = \frac{(2^5-1)(7^5-1)}2\,\zeta(5)+\color{blue}{496}\times\frac{2^4}{4!}\sqrt7\,\pi^5$$
where the sequence goes $(8,\,496,\,74168,\,20629216,\dots)$ though they are not yet in the OEIS.

II. Definitions
For simplicity, we use the Hurwitz zeta function,
$$\zeta(s,a) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac1{(k+a)^s}$$
Define the generalized functions $G_p(s)$ for prime $p=4m+3$ and odd power $s>1.$ Then
\begin{align}
G_3(s)\,\frac{\sqrt3\,(2\pi)^s}{2\,(s-1)!} + \frac1{2}(2^s-1)(3^s-1)\,\zeta(s) &= \zeta\big(s,\tfrac1{6}\big) \\[3pt]
G_7(s)\,\frac{\sqrt7\,(2\pi)^s}{2\,(s-1)!} + \frac1{2}(2^s-1)(7^s-1)\, \zeta(s) &= \zeta\big(s,\tfrac1{14}\big) + \zeta\big(s,\tfrac9{14}\big) + \zeta\big(s,\tfrac{11}{14}\big) 
\end{align}
and analogous ones for $G_{11}(s),\, G_{19}(s),$ and so on. It seems $G_p(s)$ are integer sequences.
Note: The fractions $a_k$ of $\zeta(s,a_k)$ can be found in this previous post.

III. Question
So for $s = 3,5,7,9,\dots$
\begin{align}
H'(s) = G_3(s) &= 1, 11, 301, 15371,\dots\\[3pt]
G_7(s) &= 8, 496, 74168, 20629216,\dots\\[3pt]
G_{11}(s) &= 27, 3825, 1401327, 961682625,\dots\\[3pt]
G_{19}(s) &= 99, 44385, 48864039, 100127978145,\dots\\
\end{align}
Q1: The first sequence is the known Glaisher H'-numbers. In general, how do we show that for all odd $s>1$, then $G_p(s)$  are integers?
Q2: In the OEIS link, the first has an alternative formula as binomial sums. Do the other $G_p(s)$ have as well?
